# What's wrong with names like Toad, Kyle or Tucker?

Tags: meaning

Why does George Carlin have such a [negative view](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxqCGTkV5wg) of names like Toad, Kyle or Tucker?

Why are Johnny and Eddie 'real' names, but Kyle and Tucker are 'goofy'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Todd, not Toad. Here's a Toad:

[image]

Carlin seems to favor names that are Greek, Latin, or Biblical (Nicky, Vinny, and Tony, which are diminutives of Nicholas (Greek), Vincent (Latin) and Anthony (Latin). Everything else seems tacky too him. He's got a point.

Comment: So, the names should be Latin or Greek?

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov: Or Biblical. There are some exceptions, like Arthur, or Vladeemir, for that matter. But those are few and far between.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because I think that no further explanation is possible. Some national peculiarity. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov: Oh, come on. Most Slavic names are Greek, Latin, or Biblical too.

Comment: I am not arguing,  I should only say that Tucker and Todd for foreigner sounds more brutal than Eddie and Johnny.

Comment: The popularity of Todd and Tucker and Kyle is relatively recent. Names tend to trend. See the Social Security Administration's name popularity rankings by year: https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/index.html#&ht=1

Comment: For example, search for **Tucker**  since 1960: https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/index.html#&ht=2

Comment: -1 because of your sentence *he's got a point*. Turns the answer from unbiased to biased.